# What’s the proper lane for going straight through a traffic light when formal lines don’t exist?

Tags: driving, traffic, road-signs

There is an intersection with a traffic light where I live in Golden, Colorado. You can turn both left and right at the light, in addition to proceeding straight.

The road is wide and traffic naturally forms two lanes: left-turners take the left lane and right-turners take the right. That said, the road does not have any formal lines, painted lane indicators, or signs marking the proper lanes for travel.

There have been many times when both I and the driver in the “lane” next to me attempt to go straight despite the road on the other side not being quite wide enough for two cars to pass through at the same time.

To me, taking position in the left “lane” feels correct as I’m not blocking others in the right who wish to turn right on red. I have seen both left-turn-only and right-turn-only lanes at other intersections where only two lanes exist.

Are there any laws or unwritten practices that would dictate proper lane use?

Comment: I would say that "keep right" takes precedence over not blocking the road for those who might want to turn red on right, but we don't have a "turn right on red"-rule in Denmark and I never got a driver's license.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because what does this have to do with travel?

Comment: @chx Is driving not travel?

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for the information. Why is that? I’ve never had any issues on any of the other SE sites with new lines.

Comment: Please post a link to that intersection on Google Maps. Voting as unclear until then.

Comment: Can the driver on the left proceed uninhibited, or would they have to merge to the left to avoid parked cars?  There is a likely Answer, too bad the question was closed.

Comment: **The question is perfectly clear.**  There are plenty of driving question on TSE.

Comment: In the UK (opposite side of the road of course) we don't turn [left] on a red light, so instead of avoiding blocking the red-light turners, we would want not to **be** blocked by [right] turners waiting for a clear road. But generally the issue is similar. If there are only two cars, the one in the "faster" lane would probably tread the pedal, and the other guy would defer. When there are many cars, the zipper "alternate" approach works well. Although "merge alternately" signs have been discussed, they have never been implemented, and it is left to the road sense of drivers.

Comment: The question is not travel-related: *"where I live"* makes it clear this is an issue for regular driving standards by locals. If it had asked about whether the standard is different when they visit Brazil or Belgium or Brunei, then it would be on-topic. Currently, it simply isn't.